# Андроид: отображение GIF-анимации

Tags: android

Я написал программку для просмотра прикольных гифок. Для просмотра гифок используеться WebView котрол в который я кладу примерно такой html:

```
...
img src="http://...image.gif"
...
```

Мобильный интернет очень медленный и гифка отображается как слайд-шоу.
Есть вариант перед отображением загружать файл полностью локально, а потом отображать. Это решает проблему скорости анимации, но перед тем как показать картинку нужно ждать пол минуты пока она загрузится, что тоже не вариант.

Есть ли какие-то способы решения проблемы?

Comment: Выводите треугольник «медленное соединение».  
А вообще, люди с медленным интернетом сами должны догадываться, что проблема не у приложения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разве что сразу их в ресурсы класть, можно попробовать сжимать их, но проблему медленного интернета это не решит.